# Error: opening registry "Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"

Tags: java, jar

Tengo una aplicación escrita en `Java` conectada con base de datos `MySQL`, la cual desde el `Netbeans` funciona correctamente. Ahora quisiera probarla desde la consola de comandos `cmd`. ¿Se puede?

He creado el "`Clean and Build`" y me ha generado el archivo `.jar`

¿Puedo ejecutar el jar desde cmd? Creo que sí, pero me da el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿A qué se debe el error?**

Quisiera aprender a ejecutarla desde el escritorio por ejemplo, sin necesidad de entrar a Netbeans.
¿Cómo la digo que coja el archivo "Index.java" al iniciarla?

Tengo 4 archivos ejecutables:

- 3 de ellos: JDialog
- 1 de ellos: JFrame "Index.java" (el principal).

Comment: Tienes la suficiente reputación para saber que las imágenes no son bien recibidas, puedes editar y colocar el mensaje de error en la pregunta para que sea legible de leer.

Comment: @Bicho Las imágenes son bien recibidas debido a que en el programa como ves coge las 3 imágenes perfectamente. El problema tiene que ver con Java o algún archivo de Java, no por las imágenes.

Comment: Eso es debido a problemas con la instalación/configuración de Java en tu máquina. Desde el IDE no te ocurre puesto que el IDE no va buscar los ejecutables de Java en el PATH del sistema, sino en la carpeta del JDK configurado para el proyecto. [Aquí](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7016049) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key) puedes encontrar la solución.

Comment: @E.Betanzos Cuando escribo en la consola de comandos "cmd" -> java -version me dice que no tengo ningún java instalado. Sorprendente debido a que debería estar.

Comment: Efectivamente, tienes un problema con tu instalación de Java.

Comment: @E.Betanzos No me deja instalar un archivo de Java JDK. No sé qué ocasiona el error en mi PC.

Comment: Comparte el error que estás teniendo para instalar el JDK

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106966/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-e-betanzos).